# Count all div elements and add each number inside span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show each number of div in the page in order

And add the value of each div inside span

so if I have 4 divs inside page like this

```
<div>first div</div>
<div>second div</div>
<div>third div</div>
```

every div need to show his order and be like this

```
<div>first div <span>1</span></div>
<div>second div <span>2</span></div>
<div>third div <span>3</span></div>
```

This html example code in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/CtDLe/

I need the output to be like this using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/CtDLe/1/

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Keep track of a counter, starting with `1` (like `var counter = 1;`). Iterate over the `<div>` elements by using `$("div").each(function (idx, el) { });`, and inside of there, find the inner `<span>` with `$(el).find("span")`, and set its inner text with `.text(counter++)`. Now try that and come back with problems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple `each` loop does the trick:

```
$("div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("span").text(++i);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CtDLe/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").each(function(idx,elem) {
    $("<span>").text(idx).appendTo(wherever);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("div").each(function(i, elem){
 $(elem).append($("<span>"+(i+1)+"</span>"));
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/RgMr2/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var counter = 1;
$('h1').each(function () {
    $(this).find('span').html(counter);
    counter++;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CtDLe/2/)**