# Count all div and add each number inside span in descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code from earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235548/count-all-div-elements-and-add-each-number-inside-span-using-jquery)

```
$("div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("span").text(++i);
});
```

***-- full code in action =***  http://jsfiddle.net/pm3YL/

This JQuery code count every div in the page and add the order number inside span

But I need to do the same descending order

So the output will be like this one

http://jsfiddle.net/pm3YL/1/

Instead of

http://jsfiddle.net/pm3YL/

Comment: Sounds like you need a css counter actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div span").text(function(i) {
    return $("div span").length-i;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pm3YL/5/)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
$($("div").get().reverse()).each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("span").text(++i);
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9VGhQ/)

**Another** way, using also jQuery with [**reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) is:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
$("div").reverse().each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("span").text(++i);
});
```

This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9VGhQ/3/). (Thank you [Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317927/ian) for the suggestion.)

**One more** alternative is to use the `length` (count of elements matching that selector) and go down from there using the `index` of each iteration. Then you can use this:

```
var nr_of_divs = $("div").length;
$("div").each(function (i) {
    $(this).find("span").text(nr_of_divs - i);
});
```

This demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9VGhQ/2/)

**One more**, kind of related to the one above and inspired by [Adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18292382/2256325):

```
var nr_of_divs = $("div").length;
$("div span").text(function (i) {
    return nr_of_divs - i;
});
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/pm3YL/6/)**

Comment: Another option for reversing is using this: `jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;`, and then just `$("div").reverse().each(func...`. Taken from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards

Comment: Good suggestion @Ian! added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can put something like :

```
var length_div = $("div").length

    $("div").each(function(i) {
        var tmp  = length_div-i;   
        $(this).find("span").text(tmp);
    });
```

Comment: You might want to store `$("div")` *outside* of the `.each()` loop, so that it isn't executed every iteration

Comment: @Ian absolutely right and I could also not use the tmp variable, but so it is more clear for Jim

Comment: Yeah, the `tmp` variable is fine, I just meant that running `$("div")` once will only query the DOM once, which probably is the most expensive part of most of these operations. Anyways, good example :)

Answer (score 2):

You could write a for-loop that runs in reverse through the collection, but I guess it's simpler to just subtract the counter from the number of elements to get a reverse numbering:

```
var divs = $("div"),
    l = divs.length;
divs.each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("span").text(l - i);
});
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pm3YL/3/))